# undefined struct type in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, types, struct

the following is my index.h class

```
class index
{

struct node {
        string item;
        int counter;
        vector<int> pageNumber;
    };

public:
    node* newNode (string word);
    ...

private:
    vector<node*> indexStructure;
    int lineCounter;
    int indexSize;

};
```

In my index.cpp class I have a method definition as the following:

```
node* index::newNode (string word)
{
    node* temp = new node();
    temp.item = word;
    temp.counter = 1;
    temp.pageNumber = new vector <int> (10, -1);
    temp.pageNumber[0] = lineCounter / 40;
    return temp;

}
```

when I compile, it tells me "node does not name a type" even though it is defined in the struct in index.h and my private vector variable can have the type node*.

Comment: I highly recommend not using nested classes, primarily for this reason.  When you gain more experience, you can develop your own rules for nested classes.  For your learning, it's just a big pain; not worth it.

Comment: Aside: you meant `temp->`, not `temp.`,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`node` is a nested class in `index` and thus it is called `index::node` within the global namespace.

Note that you can omit the `index::` from within the function body and thus only have to say `index::node` in the signature in your cpp file, since this is within "global namespace".

Comment: I should give you a -1 since you beat me with the same content. :-(

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry for that, I think this happens often, especially on questions like this which can be answered very quickly :)

Comment: @leemes You are right. I misread where the function was defined. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `index::node* index::newNode(string word)`. The scope necessary to do it the way you're trying is not established until after the end of the function name.